# GRASS 7.2.0 doesn't start on PC

Tags: grass-gis, unicodeencodeerror, grass-7.2

when I want to start the program a black window opens and show me the next message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\grass72.py", line 1971, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\grass72.py", line 1822, in main
    set_paths(grass_config_dir=grass_config_dir)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0\etc\grass72.py", line 620, in set_paths
    os.environ['MANPATH'] = to_text_string(addons_man_path)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\os.py", line 420, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

How can I get past this?

Comment: @AndreJ - please post your comment  as an answer below, thanks

Comment: @AndreJ I have reopened for you to add your comment as an answer

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreJ. That solution works very well. Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have a non-ASCII character in your Windows user name (or project or file name), and therefore in the path name to where temporary data is stored.

You can overcome this by creating a new Windows user without non-ASCII characters.